# disable previous dates - fscalender swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm using fscalender in my project. I have to choose start date and end date,in which when user selected start date the end date calendar view should disable the previous dates of selected date.How can I achieve this.

`

```
 var satrtDte:Date?
`func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
        if isFromEndDate == true{
            if let start = satrtDte{
                if date .compare(start) == .orderedAscending {
                    return false
                    
                }else {
                    return true
                }
            }
            
        }
        return true
    }
```

``
satrtDte contains start Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two method from the delegate `FSCalendarDataSource` to select start and end date:

```
    var startDate: Date() = // declare your start Date
    var endDate: Date() = // declare your end Date

    func minimumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
        return startDate
    }

    func maximumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
        return endDate
    }
```

Comment: func minimumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
        if isFromToDate == true{
            return satrtDte
        }
        return 
    }
in this case when this condition is true then I have to set minimum dates otherwise I have to view the calendar as it is so my question is what should I return In this else case

Comment: If i undertood this correctly I think you can return `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)`, in this way you will have  00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970, that shoul be the start of the Date type. More information here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780353-init